# MySQL Not Executing Create Procedure Request

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySQl, but when I select the code to run the creation, nothing happens. I don't get an error or anything at all in the action output box. It looks like MySQL is processing the request because of the loading animation next to the script's name but it stops shortly after. I can execute similar procedures like this one and different commands just fine, so I'm not sure why this one isn't working

```
CREATE TABLE odd(num INT PRIMARY KEY);

DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE insertOdd() BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    SET x = 0; 
    loop_label: LOOP
        SET x = (2 * x) + 1;
        IF x > 20 THEN
            LEAVE loop_label;
        END IF;
        IF x = 5 THEN
            ITERATE loop_label;
        END IF;
        IF x = 15 THEN
            ITERATE loop_label;
        END IF;
            INSERT INTO odd(num) VALUES x;
            ITERATE loop_label;
    END LOOP loop_label; 
END
DELIMITER ;
```

I thought it had something to do with the way I formatted the IF statements so I adjusted them to something uglier to see if anything would happen but it didn't work

(The script is meant to insert odd numbers into a table through a loop by the way but I don't think that's really relevant)

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: strange, it's still not working. i might have to check in with my professor for this

Comment: Beg your pardon, `END|`

Comment: Workbench has a "Stored Procedures" tab: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: You set the delimiter to `|` but you never specify that delimiter

Comment: 1) Follow the advice provided by @RiggsFolly and add the SP statement termination; 2) Fix syntax error, add parenthesis for `INSERT INTO odd(num) VALUES (x);`.

Comment: hi everyone, thanks for your help
turns out it was because i didn't add '|' to the end of the stored procedure to indicate the end of the declaration